# How do I activate a segue from a tableView where the datasource is from another swift file?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, datasource, segue

I have a tableView in my ViewController, the datasource for this table is from another swift file: DataSource.swift. This is the code of the datasource file:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class Datasource: NSData, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

let itemsArray = ["Item 1","Item 2","Item 3","Item 4"]


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemsArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier:"test")
    cell.textLabel!.text = self.itemsArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
}
```

I tried adding this code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mainToDetail", sender: self)

}
```

But it gave me an error, I also tried this code and it didn't work as well:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    ViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("mainToDetail", sender: ViewController)

}
```

I want to add a functionality where when I click a row in the table, a segue from the ViewController is activated to show the DetailViewController.
Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this in many ways. For example,

- hold reference of ViewController in `Datasource`'s property
- Passing closure
- Delegate Pattern

But using delegate pattern is my preference.

---

First, you need to create `DatasourceDelegate` protocol.

```
protocol DatasourceDelegate: class{
    func didSelectGoToMainMenu( datasource datasource: Datasource)
}
```

---

Second, In `Datasource` class, you will have a `DatasourceDelegate` object. Like this

```
class Datasource: NSObject,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{
    //...
    weak var delegate: DatasourceDelegate?
    //...
}
```

and in `tableView(_ :didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)`. It will call `DatasourceDelegate` function. Like this

```
extension Datasource: UITableViewDelegate{

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        delegate?.didSelectGoToMainMenu(datasource: self)
    }
}
```

---

Finally, In your seperated ViewController class, You set the view controller to conform `DatasourceDelegate` protocol. Like this

```
class myViewController: UIViewController, DatasourceDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ////////

        let dataSource = Datasource()
        dataSource.delegate = self

        tableView.dataSource = dataSource
        tableView.delegate = dataSource

    }

    // this function will be called when someone select a row
    func didSelectGoToMainMenu(datasource datasource: Datasource) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("mainToDetail", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to thank you my friend, that worked great! Thanks a million.

Comment: one more question if you can, can you tell me how to implement the prepareforsegue method in this case? I've been trying but couldn't figure our how. I'm very new to working with protocol (1st time i use it)

Comment: I think you can override prepareForSegue in myViewController. 'prepareForSegue' will be called automatically when it performs segue in 'didSelectGoToMainMenu' in myViewController.